# Some admin users can not see all the products

Tags: product, magento2.3, admin

We have come across a strange issue.

We are 3 people with admin privileges in our Magento admin site.

When we search for a specific SKU in filter, 2 of us get the same result and 1 get a totally different result.

2 of us get 2600 records and we can go to the next page etc, but the last one he only gets 1 record found but is showing 999 records but are not able to go to next page. When i uses the tick boxes on the left side to tick 1 box then all the boxes gets ticked.

We have made sure that we are using the same filters etc.

Anyone that had the same issue knows how to fix this?

thanks.

Comment: In the ui_bookmark table, try deleting any entries related to the user that doesnt see all the products. Possibly some filter or something invisible is bookmarked. You wont break anything by deleting rows from that table.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for the tips, but I'm not 100%  what you mean. where can i do this?

Comment: In the database

Comment: Thanks, will test that out now and come back if it worked.

Comment: thanks!! You are a life saviour

Comment: Added my comment as an answer. Will be appreciative if you could accept as the official answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ui_bookmark table, try deleting any entries related to the user that doesnt see all the products. Possibly some filter or something invisible is bookmarked. You wont break anything by deleting rows from that table.